# How can I determine the outcome of off-screen combat between NPCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, npc

My players will get a choice as they are assaulting a castle. There will be three magical siege engines they will need to stop so their troops don't get slaughtered.

Now knowing they have a fight with the big bad coming, they can either sneak in and stop all three towers themselves, or just stop one then move in to the boss fight leaving the other two towers to their retainers.

Should the players decide to leave the other towers to their retainers I want a simple way to decide some off screen combat because the retainers might die if it's left to them. How would you guys handle it?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question, as I'd never noticed the question it's been marked as a duplicate of, which has a really great answer.  Thanks, and welcome to RPG.SE ^_^

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? The other question explicitly asks about the case when a npc vs npc battle is not in background. It does mention background battles but they are not explicitly addressed by the answers. Quote from the other question: `If it's a full "background battle" then I'd assume the highest CR group wins, with losses. But if this is not the case ... `

Comment: @findusl The questions may not be identical but the answers there certainly seem to address this question. If there is something missing the OP can [edit] this question to make the distinction clearer. We can then reopen it.